# Suggested promotion standard for develop branches

Tags: git, git-flow

We have what I have come to know as a standard pattern in GIT:  Master -> Develop -> Feature

Our team usually finishes a feature, have it code reviewed and approved before promoting to Develop.  But in this case we are being asked to review and promote unfinished code.

The up-side to this is that the team will stay closer to parity.  The downside if my approval will be on code that is not ready to ship in our develop branch.

Curious if others out in the coding world have faced this situation and how you proceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case, we have another branch, a **Release** branch, for preparing, reviewing, testing, and approving codes planned to be shipped/released/deployed. It is branched-out from **Develop**, which is only used as an *integration* branch for merging *individual* features.

It is partly based on the Gitflow Workflow described in this Atlassian Git Tutorial:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Codes in **Develop** are generally treated as still work-in-progress or unfinished. Passing the reviews and tests before merging **Feature** branches just means that the feature works by itself. But there is still the case of how that feature works with the *other* features that could still be under development. The feature *itself* may already be ready for release but *all* the features combined (old and new) may not be yet.

That is where the **Release** branch comes in. We branch-out from **Develop** after a specific set of features are merged. It is similar to saying "we now have a release candidate code containing these set of new features". Final integration tests, code reviews, and approvals are then done on this **Release** branch. Once all checks passes, it is finally merged to **Master** and released.

```
Master   -------------------------------------O (product release)
                                             /
Release                                 --O---
                                       /      \
Develop  ----O--------------O---O--O-----------O---
              \            /   /  /
FeatureA ---------O--O-----   /  /
               \             /  /
FeatureB ---------O--O-------  /
                \             /
FeatureC ------------O--------
```

If something's wrong in the **Release** branch, either (1) we create a fix branch from **Develop** then merge the fix branch to **Release**, or (2) we apply the fix directly to the **Release** branch (if it's "small" enough) then merge it back to **Develop** later.

The advantage of having a separate **Release** branch is that approval is now done on a branch that contains the complete code-to-be-released. Doing tests and performing reviews on this branch ensures that we're checking the code as a whole with all the features integrated together. It's clear that there should be no more new features to be added/removed to this branch, similar to saying "this is the release candidate code waiting for approval".

An added advantage is that the **Release** branch is kept separate from the possibly and usually ongoing development in the **Develop** branch. People who have the responsibility of approving releases will only need to focus on the **Release** branch.